# JavaScript that adds behavior to all links should exclude some

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the fallowing smooth scrolling script:

```
<!-- Smooth scroll JS -->
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('a[href^="#"]').click(function(e) {

    jQuery('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: jQuery(this.hash).offset().top}, 1000);

    return false;

    e.preventDefault();

});
</script>
```

The problem is that it affects all link to an id (as intended) and causes a conflict with toggle script.

I need to add a condition to the script so that the links in the #work_tabs div are not affected.

```
        <div id="work_tabs">
             <ul>
              <li><a href="#films" class="navLink">Films</a></li>
              <li><a href="#tv_films" class="navLink">TV Films</a></li>
              <li><a href="#tv_shows" class="navLink">TV Shows</a></li>
              <li><a href="#special_events" class="navLink">Special Events</a></li>
            </ul> 
        </div>
```

I tried adding the condition myself but i'm still new to JS and have no idea how to achieve this.

How could I make the script ignore the links in the work_tabs id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `not()` function:

```
jQuery('a[href^="#"]').not('#work_tabs > a').click(function(e) {

    jQuery('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: jQuery(this.hash).offset().top}, 1000);

    return false;

    e.preventDefault();

});
```

This will exclude any anchor tags inside that div.

Read more [here](http://api.jquery.com/not/).

Comment: Great solution, worked as intended. Thank your for the link, hope it will clear my problems in the future. :)

Answer (score 2):

One way to go about it is add a class to the items that can be toggled and change your element selector to point to that.

```
jQuery('.toggle').click(function(e) {
```

Comment: I'm afraid that wouldn't solve the problem. The toggle script works but the problem is that when the user clicks one of the #work_tabs links not only they toggle the content but smooth scrolls to it as well. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery `.not()` function to remove the intended elements

Use `jQuery('a[href^="#"]').not('#work_tabs > a')`

```
<!-- Smooth scroll JS -->
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('a[href^="#"]').not('#work_tabs > a').click(function(e) {

    jQuery('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: jQuery(this.hash).offset().top}, 1000);

    return false;

    e.preventDefault();

});
</script>
```